# Auth0 lock not showing sign up option

Tags: ionic2, auth0

I'm using the Auth0 lock in my Ionic 2 mobile application.
I've recently updated to the latest Auth0(7.0.3) and Auth0-lock(10.0.0) versions.
Now I've noticed that the options for the lock have changed, primarily the names of those options. Here the API for Auth0-lock(10.0.0) =>  https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#allowsignup-boolean-
Previously there were the following options:

```
var options = {
    disableSignupAction: false,
    signupLink: myUrl
}
```

Those should now be

```
var options = {
    allowSignUp: true,
    signUpLink: myUrl
}
```

These options are passed into the constructor of Auth0Lock:

```
lock = new Auth0Lock(auth0ClientID, auth0Domain, options);
```

I'm certain most of my other options are applied to the lock as the `closable: false` option I have included in options applies to the lock resulting in the removal of the close button.

I have tried some variations in capital letters of `allowSignUp` and `signUpLink` as the old api used a different property name for the sign up link -> `signupLink`, however none of the combinations seem to work.

How can I enable the sign up action for the Auth0 lock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These options are correct for Lock v10:

```
var options = {
  allowSignUp: true,
  signUpLink: myUrl
}
```

`allowSignup` has a default value of `true`, and providing a value to `signUpLink` will also force `allowSignUp` to `true`.

However, keep in mind that the signup option will only appear if your client (app) has a database connection enabled. Also, if the database connection has sign ups disabled or you are using a custom database which doesn't have a create script, then the sign up screen won't be available.

Additionally you can find what changed and a migration guide at https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/migration-guide

Comment: I have since updated to a later version of the Auth0 Lock (10.4.1+), the problem is now resolved.